# Flex drop down list for Air mobile

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flexbuilder

Is there any dropdownlist for flex mobile , which can be used for free in commercial app and not paid one

Answer (score 0):

Igor Costa has made a [ComboBox](http://www.igorcosta.org/?p=360) that can be used for free. But to be honest, I'd rather make my own based on a SkinnablePopupContainer (that's what he did as well and basically that's the way to go if you don't want to use a custom Callout), cause modifying other people's code often takes more time than to build your own component.